# Handle mouse events and pass them to a window behind,

Tags: wpf, mouseevent, transparency

I have windows with transparent backgrounds which are overlapping.
I want them to both handle mouse events and let them pass to the window that is in a lower Z-order which also has to handle the events.

The problem is that if I set background to "Transparent" - the window will not handle the events and just let them pass to the window behind it.
If I set the background to "almost transparent"

```
(this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(1, 0, 0, 0));
```

it will handle the events but will also block the window behind it from receiving them...

How can I solve this?

Comment: do you want to have a global event that will fire and affect each window?

Comment: I'd like to keep it as simple as possible. If you're talking about hooking to windows messages, I'd rather not...

Comment: well out of my mind I think of a simple idea, haven't tested it yet, but will using datacontex or even datastore and behavior triggers may serve your cause?

Comment: well if I understand correctly you want once an event is fired in windows1 then it should also be fired on windows2?

Comment: yes, this is what I want :)

Comment: I will try to make an example, show me the code for the event you want.